# Why my local storage is not saving after page refresh

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, use-effect

In my react i have the following code:

```
useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('level', level.toString())
        localStorage.setItem('currentExperience', currentExperience.toString())
        localStorage.setItem('challengesCompleted', challengesCompleted.toString())
    }, [level, currentExperience, challengesCompleted])
```

I dont wanna lost this data when i page refresh!

Comment: Perhaps you set them all to null when the page refreshes.

Comment: and how can i fix this?

Comment: I don't know if what I said is true, start by investigating if that is so.

Comment: How this variables (level, currentExperience...) are initialized?

Comment: With useState : const [level, setLevelUp] = useState(1)
    const [currentExperience, setCurrentExperience] = useState(30)

    const [challengesCompleted, setChallengeCompleted] = useState(0)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, check if these keys are updated in other part of your application

Comment: makesure your default/initState value is not null, maybe you can set condition for check teh value before setItem

Comment: is not null, i give a initial state before all. On console, show me the storage, but when i refresh the page, the data goes to hell

Answer (score 1):

useEffect will run every time when the value of level, currentExperience, challengesCompleted will change. When you refresh your page the value of these variables night not be your desired values but useEffect will run and eventually set the values to the local storage. You need to wither wrap your code for setting values in an if condition or take it out of useEffect.

Comment: you can add a console.log in your use effect to see what are the values when useEffect runs or use debugger and add breakpoints to see whats going on